# How to initialize Hive Metastore in Windows 10 (Derby)

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I have not initialized Metastore for Hive.

How can I do that? I know I have to run schematool with `--service metastore`, but am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/DB/HADOOP/Hive-3.1.2/bin/nitSchema does not exist
```

[image]

Comment: I think you'll have better luck running Hive/Hadoop in a Linux VM

Comment: I can run Hadoop, Pig, Spark, Kafka, Sqoop without any problem. So please help me.